# The attribute I am trying to use is undefined when it is defined when I console log my object

Tags: angular, typescript

**QUESTION:**
Why is it saying my Grade_ID is undefined when it is really defined when I console log it?
How can I solve this problem?

**HAVE TRIED:**
I have tried debugging this problem for the last couple of hours that is why I came to stack overflow for a solution.
-I have googled.
-I have checked previous stack overflow questions and it will not aid me with this current problem.

```
//my Grade class
 export class Grade{
 public Grade_ID: number;
 public Grade_Mark: number;
 public Subject_Name: string;

constructor(Grade_ID: number, Grade_Mark: number, Subject_Name: string){
Grade_ID = Grade_ID;
Grade_Mark = Grade_Mark;
Subject_Name = Subject_Name;
  }
}

//my .ts file
  grades: Grade[];
  grade: Grade;

 viewSubjectMarks() {
this.studentGrades.forEach((element1) => {
  if (element1.Student_ID === this.Student_ID) {
    console.log(element1)
    this.grade.Grade_ID = element1.Grade_ID;
    this.grade.Grade_Mark = element1.Grade_Mark;
    this.subjects.forEach((element2) => {
      if (element1.Subject_ID === element2.Subject_ID) {
        this.grade.Subject_Name = element2.Subject_Name;
        this.grades.push(this.grade);
      }
    });
  }
});
  }
}

this.grade = {
  Grade_ID: 0,
  Grade_Mark: 0,
  Subject_Name: '',
};
```

[image: **enter image description here**]

Comment: where is the value for `this.grade` is it initialized before the `viewSubjectMarks()` is called?

Comment: Which of those two `console.log` statements are we seeing the result of? `console.log(element1)`?

Comment: Please post code, error messages, markup, etc. **as text**, not (just) as a *picture* of text. Why: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/157247

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `this.grade` is `undefined`. Note that the error is saying it can't **set** `Grade_ID` on `undefined`. It's not saying `Grade_ID` is `undefined`, and it's not saying `element1` is `undefined`.

In the code you've shown, `this.grade` is assigned a value **after** the loop. Before the loop it has the value `undefined`, hence the error message. It needs to be assigned the object you've shown *before* the loop.

Comment: I am looking into your answer thanks for the contribution

Answer (score 0):

grade is undefined in your class until `this.garde = {...}`. An easy way to solve this problem would be to use a class property:

```js
  grade: Grade = {
    Grade_ID: 0,
    Grade_Mark: 0,
    Subject_Name: ''
  };
```

Comment: Hi, when I do this it says cannot assign 'Grade' because it is not a variable.

Comment: `Grade` is an interface.

Comment: I added my Grade class in my question sorry about that

Answer (score 0):

Want to edit this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61487004/12834817) but edit queue is full so have to answer it separately.

Within constructor, values should be assigned by using `this`.

```
      constructor(Grade_ID:number, Grade_Mark:number, Subject:string){
        this.Grade_ID=Grade_ID;
        this.Grade_Mark=Grade_Mark;
        this.Subject=Subject;
      }
```